# Dimensional scaling implementation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not familiar with the concept of dimensional scaling at all. Anyone please help me with this problem.

I need to understand how they obtained equations \eqref{2} from equations \eqref{1} in the paper

- Jose ́I. Adachi, Emmanuel Detournay, Anthony P. Peirce, *Analysis of the classical pseudo-3D model for hydraulic fracture with equilibrium height growth across stress barriers*, International Journal of Rock Mechanics & Mining Sciences 47 (2010) 625–639, doi:[10.1016/j.ijrmms.2010.03.008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijrmms.2010.03.008), [author pdf](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Epeirce/Adachi_Detournay_Peirce_IJRM_V47_p625_639_2010.pdf)

so I can do the same when I change $Q_0$ from a constant to a variable function in time. Summary as below:

Scaling equations:
$$
\begin{matrix}
ξ=x/l, & ζ=z/h_*,& τ=t/t_*,& γ=l/l_*,& λ=h/h_*, \\
Π=p/p_*, & Ψ=q/q_*, & \bar Ψ=\bar q/q_*,& Ω=w/w_*,& \bar Ω = \bar w /w_*
\end{matrix}\label{1}\tag{15}
$$

> The six characteristic quantities that have been introduced are identified by setting to unity, six of the dimensionless groups that emerge from the governing equations when they are expressed in terms of the dimensionless variables. The remaining two groups are numbers that control the problem. After some algebraic manipulation, we obtain the following expressions for the characteristic quantities:
> $$
> \begin{split} 
> l_* &=\frac{πH^{4}∆σ^{4}}{4E^{'3} μQ_0 },\\
> h_* &=H \\ 
> t_* &=\frac{π^{2} H^{6} ∆σ^{5}}{4μE^{'4}Q_0^{2} },\\ 
> p_* &=∆σ, \\
> q &=\frac{Q_0}{2H},\\
> w & =\frac{πH∆σ}{2E^{'}}=M_0∆σ
> \end{split} \label{2}\tag{16}
> $$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have voted to migrate to math.stackexchange, as while this no doubt arose during research, it is not research _in mathematics_ (have a browse of some of the other questions here :). Good luck!

Comment: Probably [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @David Roberts: yes this is part of my research studies. I want to do some changes in one parameter Q0 but I have no idea how to get those quantities in eq(16) in the same way instructed in the paper. Really hope if anyone familiar with dimensional scaling/analysis can help.

Comment: @abx: I'm not sure about that. The governing equations of the problem started from physics but what I need help here is pure math?

Comment: Stats.stackexchange.com is appropriate...but still the question should be made more specific to be there. You cannot ask just help me with this paper type questions. Question should be self contained

Comment: You want help for a physical problem involving purely with the math part of the problem. But ironically that doest mean the question belongs to pure math. Both are fifferent.

Comment: @ Rajesh Dachiraju: the problem itself is quite complicated so I only put the two equation sets which i think relevant here to avoid confusing readers. I attached the reference paper just in case I missed informing something.

Comment: I'm not I agree with Rajesh about stats.se. This feels to me like it should be symbol pushing, and maybe using some formulas that come from the physics side of things. It's very much a maths question from where I stand. The only issue is that  the equations (16) require than (15), but other equations from before that. The question as written is thus not self-contained. As a point of grammar, I would not say this is "pure math", but "purely mathematical", as pure mathematics has a much narrower definition. I hope this helps, rather than the opposite.

Comment: Thank you David for clearly pointing out the major problems here.

Comment: @Hai you're welcome. I was on a tablet writing my previous comment, and it ate some words! I meant to say "the equations (16) require not just (15), but other equations from before that" (and "I'm not sure I agree", to open).